# lower and upper bound on the unit disk

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

let $a>0$ and $b>0$ constant, $D$ the unit disk  and

$f(x,y)=a + \frac{2(x^2 + y^2)}{\rho^2}ab + \frac{1}{\rho^4}(x^2 + y^2)^2(3a+b)$

find $\sup_{(x,y)\in D}{f(x,y)}$ and $\inf_{\rho\in]0,1[}\sup_{(x,y)\in D}{f(x,y)}$

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function (of $\rho$ that André found on the upper answer) is monotonically decreasing with $\rho$, and it's inf will be attained at "$\rho = 1$", meaning that

$$
\inf_{\rho \in ]0,1[}\sup_{(x,y)\in D}f(x,y)=a+2ab+3a+b=4a+b+2ab
$$

Comment: Yes, I looked at the $\sup$ of the $\sup$.

Comment: You shoulnd't have deleted your answer. It contained the expression of the $\sup$!

Answer (score 1):

Your function is positive and maximal when $x^2+y^2$ is maximal. Hence the $\sup$ is 
$$
a + \frac 2 {\rho^2} ab + \frac {3a+b}{\rho^4}
$$

Comment: The $\inf$ is not $\infty$. Just pick some fixed value for $\rho$ and the function will have a finite value, meaning that its inf is smaller.